# i cant install Apps in my Android despite having more than 1GB memory

Tags: applications, insufficient-memory

Each time i try installing apps on my android phone, it keeps taking my to settings/storage asking me to delete some apps.

But i have 1GB phone and 7GB SDcard memory left.

Please what is the way forward?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! For a starter, please take a look at our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info). Then please see that you can [edit] your question and add a few more details. As it's currently put, there's not much specific we can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

First you must know that SD card cannot be used for aps as is, you can do that with apps like APPS2SD or link2sd, or if you have phone running android 6.0+ you can adopt sd card so it becames like internal storage but you can't use it with other phones until you format it. 
Most phones doesn't allow app install when you reach 1 gb of free internal memory, because of apps cache and such. What you can do is clearing cache from Settings>storage or with Ccleaner, also if you have some google apps that you don't need/use (gmail, google app, google movies, news and such) you can uninstall updates for them from app manager and than disable them to prevent them from updateing again that could free-up some memory.